# Winforms - UserControl OnGotFocus event

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to find the event which is invoked when the `UserControl` is brought to front.

I saw the `OnLoad` event, but it works on for first load.

`OnGotFocus` doesn't also not invoke.

Anyone?

Comment: any code to share? Did you register an event handler for `GotFocus`

Comment: Define brought to front?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Please explain the feature so that one may can help you with potential alternatives.

Comment: Maybe [Activated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.activated%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event?

Comment: Tried registerring to getfocus. @Dialecticus No activated for UserControl, I managed to do what is needed using : OnVisibleChanged. TY

Comment: There is not anything the user can do to change the Z-order of a child control.  Only your code can do that.  There is no event for this, it is a case of "how can you not know what your code does".  Controls would be very hard to use if there was an event for *everything* you can do with them.

Answer (score 0):

Who is the Parent of UserControl?

You can handle it by the control that contains the UserControl. If the UserControl is in the TabControl, you can manage the event enterPage, or if it is a WindowsForm need to trigger the event of the UserControl from the form that contains it. I do this.

```
UserControlStandardMacchine uc = null;
private void tabPageMacchine_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    if (uc!= null) 
    {
        uc = new UserControlStandardMacchine (); 
        uc.Parent = this; 
        uc.Dock = DockStyle.Fill; 
        uc.refreshData (); 
    } 
    else 
    {
        uc.refreshData(); 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The lower level approach would be to override the WndProc method. This gives you a control over any type of messages your form is processing.

The activate message has a number 0x006. Below the link to a list of available processes:
http://wiki.winehq.org/List_Of_Windows_Messages

Sample implementation can look like this:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    private const int WM_ACTIVATE = 0x006;
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == WM_ACTIVATE)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Activate");
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
}
```